# How to force the call of a SSL certificate? (Cache)

Tags: ssl-certificate

I use a SSL certificate for our domain. 
The New Certificate is valid until 15th November.
On some Computers (same Browsers) the Certificate is expired.
After cleaning the cache and restarting the browser, the domain is working as expected.
My Problem: Not every customer knows to clean the cache, so i need a solution on the server side.

For my Computer i already tried cleaning the cache - works!

Answer (score 0):

you should clear SSL cache from the browser programmatically for that domain. So you wouldn't need to do it manually.